# Python Selenium Find Xpath of table

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to access the following website with selenium using python. I've been trying to find the xpath of the table, but it seems to be hidden. Does anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

https://www.stakingrewards.com/cryptoassets

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("window-size=1200x600")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

driver.get(f'https://www.stakingrewards.com/cryptoassets')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//html/body/")
print(iframes[0].get_attribute("outerHTML")) ```
````

Comment: Apologies, it's fixed now @Robson

Comment: Does it have to be an xpath? Why not `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ReactTable")`

Comment: Wow that was much easier than I thought. Thanks @Robson!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Do you know why the following won't return anything? (i'm find the next page button) driver.find_element_by_class_name("pagination_page-item__2E9K- button inverse pagination_next__1fRhW") @Robson

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@class='rt-table']"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below css_selector to click on next button.

```
button[data-testid='next-page-button']
```

Note that there are two next page button, one is which can be seen right after the website is opened up, and the second one is in bottom of it.

Since it is always gonna find the first one, I think you should be good to go with that.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work using driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"button[data-testid='next-page-button']") @cruisepandey

Comment: @RexG : Cause that is css selector, not xpath, try this `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[data-testid='next-page-button']")`